# Unexpected result in a simple example

Tags: python

```
   def solve(numLegs, numHeads):
        for numSpiders in range(0, numHeads + 1):
            for numChicks in range(0, numHeads - numSpiders + 1):
                numPigs = numHeads - numChicks - numSpiders
                totLegs = 4*numPigs + 2*numChicks + 6*numSpiders 
                if totLegs == numLegs:
                    return [numPigs, numChicks, numSpiders]
        return [None, None, None]

    def barnYard(heads, legs):
        pigs, chickens, spiders = solve(legs, heads)
        if pigs == None:
            print "There is no solution."
        else:
            print 'Number of pigs: ', pigs
            print 'Number of Chickens: ', chickens
            print 'Number of Spider: ', spiders

    barnYard(20,56) # 8 pigs - 12 chickens
    barnYard(21,62) # 10 pig - 11 chickens
```

20 heads and 56 legs returns 8 pigs and 12 chickens, so I made it 21 and 62 to add a spider, but it still returns pigs and chickens, whats wrong in the code?

Thanks!

Comment: Not that that's an error in your code, but spiders have eight legs :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is correct - in the first iteration of the outermost `for` loop, `numChicks` is `0`. Since `solve` returns as soon as it finds a valid match, another possible valid match won't be attempted.

You could change the `return` statement into a `yield` statement and iterate over `solve`'s results to get all possible combinations.

For instance:

```
def solve(numLegs, numHeads):
     for numBees in range(0, numHeads + 1):
             for numChicks in range(0, numHeads - numBees + 1):
                     numPigs = numHeads - numChicks - numBees
                     totLegs = 4*numPigs + 2*numChicks + 6*numBees 
                     if totLegs == numLegs:
                             yield [numPigs, numChicks, numBees]

def barnYard(heads, legs):
    for pigs, chickens, bees in solve(legs, heads):
             print 'Number of pigs: ', pigs
             print 'Number of chickens: ', chickens
             print 'Number of bees: ', bees

barnYard(20,56)
```

will output:

```
Number of pigs:  8
Number of chickens:  12
Number of bees:  0

Number of pigs:  6
Number of chickens:  13
Number of bees:  1

Number of pigs:  4
Number of chickens:  14
Number of bees:  2

Number of pigs:  2
Number of chickens:  15
Number of bees:  3

Number of pigs:  0
Number of chickens:  16
Number of bees:  4
```

Answer (score 2):

There is absolutely nothing wrong with your code. That's a completely valid result. With 10 pigs and 11 chickens, you get `10+11=21` heads, and `10*4 + 11*2` = 62 legs.

So it returns a correct result.

Now if you change that to 10 heads and 62 legs, and also change the code to have 8 legs for a spider as they tend to do, then you get the result 3 pigs, 1 chicken and 6 spiders.

Your code simply tries spiders last, so you wont get any spiders unless it *has* to be spiders.

Answer (score 2):

A linear system with 2 equations and 3 variables is under-determined -- there may be multiple solutions for any given set of parameters; and this is indeed the case for the code you're showing.  Nothing wrong with the code, if what you want is to get the solution (if any) with as few spiders as possible.

If you want to get the solution (if any) with *as many* spiders as possible, try "many spiders" first, for example change the outer loop, which is now

```
    for numSpiders in range(0, numHeads + 1):
```

i.e., first tries to get a solution with no spiders at all, then if that fails tries with one, and so forth, to be instead:

```
    for numSpiders in reversed(range(0, numHeads + 1)):
```

which goes the other way round (that's what the `reversed` is for) and will try `numHeads` spiders first, then `numHeads-1`, and so forth.

(Your equations are actually Diophantine ones, i.e., strictly integer-based, which has important implications when compared to ordinary linear equations which admit fractional solutions, but your issue here is not tied to Diophantine-equation problems, just to the bit about underdetermined linear systems).

Comment: I bet he wasn't expecting the term "Diophantine equations" when he wrote his question.